# how to update the element of a 3-d nested array in mongodb?

Tags: mongodb

I want to update the value of an element in a nested array in MongoDB. All I have is a key which I use to check and modify its value.

```
{
    details:{
        name:"sweta",
        age:"12"
    },
    imageNames:[
       0:{
          userData:[
             0:{
                imageName : "0_abc_0.jpg",
                state:"hold"
             },
             1:{
                imageName : "1_def_1.jpg",
                state:"hold"
             }
          ]
       },
       1:{
          userData:[
             0:{
                imageName : "0_kkk_0.jpg",
                state:"hold"
             },
             1:{
                imageName : "1_jjj_1.jpg",
                state:"hold"
             }
          ]
       },

    ]

}



 let imageName = "abc.jpg"
 const [name,ex] = imageName.split('.');
 const regex = new RegExp(`\\d_${name}_\\d.${ex}`,"gi");
 let state = 'completed';

 db.update(
    {
        "details.name":"sweta","imageNames":{
            "$elemMatch":{
                "userData.imageName":{"$regex":regex}
            }
        }
    },
    { $set: { 'imageNames.$.userData.$.state': state }}
  )
```

I am having a name and imageName to filter out. But the imageName what I am having is "abc.jpg" that's why I am using regex.

I want to update the state "hold" to "completed" so how to do that?
Anyone any idea? I tried but I am getting an error.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using MongoDB version > `3.6` You can use `arrayFilters` to get right index of the `image` a quick exemple:

```
db.users.updateOne({
    'details.name': 'sweta',
    'imageNames.userData.imageName': {
        $regex: '_abc_'
    }
}, {
    $set: {
        'imageNames.$[].userData.$[data].state': 'completed'
    }
}, {
    arrayFilters: [{
        'data.imageName': {
            $regex: "_abc_"
        }
    }]
})
```